# Loading sound once for all the activity

Tags: android, soundpool

Iam trying to use soundpool to play sound in my android app. I have 3 activities where i have to play sound. So can i load sounds globally once only when application starts?? Can i make a global class and load all the sound once and use them in other activities.

Comment: Try using Services, as music is always a background job unless you are giving user controller to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example

```
//start service
Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
startService(svc);

//Add in manifest file
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name="com.package.name.BackgroundSoundService" />

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idil);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can load your audio in a global class. Thankfully android is providing us such class called Application.java.

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    private static final String TAG = "TestApp";

    private static TestApp sTestApp;

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sTestApp = this;
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1); //Volume should have to be between 0.0 to 1.0
    }

    public static TestApp getInstance() {
        return sTestApp;
    }

    public void play() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Then declare this as application class in your manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".TestApp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        .........
</application>
```

Now this class will be started automatically when your application starts and will be destroyed after your application completely destroys.

Now you can play the audio by calling

```
TestApp.getInstance().play();
```

from wherever you want.